# What patterns does PowerShell -like operator support?

Tags: powershell, operators, pattern-matching, wildcard

I was not able to find any reference about syntax of the PowerShell `-like` operator.

Windows PowerShell reference on [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) states only:

> -Like
>   Description: Match using the wildcard character (*).

Though by experimenting I've found that it also supports the `?` and the `[]` (set).

Is there any other syntax supported? Is there any definitive reference to the `-like` operator?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The help for [about_Comparison_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) indeed claims wildcard support. It fails to specify what, exactly, a wildcard is.

> -Like
>         Description: Match using the wildcard character (*).

Further digging into help [about_Wildcards](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847812.aspx) we learn that these aren't your grandpa's wildcards:

> ```
> Windows PowerShell supports the following wildcard characters.
>
>     Wildcard Description        Example  Match             No match
>     -------- ------------------ -------- ----------------- --------
>     *        Matches zero or    a*       A, ag, Apple      banana
>              more characters
>
>     ?        Matches exactly    ?n       an, in, on        ran
>              one character in 
>              the specified 
>              position
>
>     [ ]      Matches a range    [a-l]ook book, cook, look  took
>              of characters
>
>     [ ]      Matches specified  [bc]ook  book, cook        hook
>              characters
> ```

The link to wildcard help is mentioned on the See also -section in about_Comparision_Operators help.

Comment: PowerShell globbing is more like Unix shells than CMD.

Comment: If you want to match the `*` character specifically, put it in brackets `[*]`.