# What is wrong with this PowerShell -Match wildcard?

Tags: powershell, wildcard

After reading this http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_conditional_operators.htm I tried to apply the recommended use of wildcards, but utterly failed:

```
PS C:\Workspace> $a = "ABC_1608.txt"
PS C:\Workspace> $a -Match "ABC_????.txt"
Bad argument to operator '-match': parsing "ABC_????.txt" - Nested quantifier ?..
At line:1 char:10
+ $a -Match <<<<  "ABC_????.txt"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadOperatorArgument
```

But this sanity check worked:

```
PS C:\Workspace> $a = "abc"
PS C:\Workspace> $a -Match "a?c"
True
```

Then I tied the regex and it worked but I do not want to use regex for a good and sufficient reason I am not going to enter into debates about:

```
PS C:\Workspace> $a = "ABC_1608.txt"
PS C:\Workspace> $a -Match "ABC_\d{4}\.txt"
True
```

Am I not using the wildcards correctly in the first example?

Comment: `-match` is regexes, wildcards is `-like`.

Comment: So the linked article is wrong, is it?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26778044/3905079

Comment: @ajeh as a matter of fact, yes that linked article is full of errors.

Comment: @ajeh yes, it's wrong. `'1949' -match '19?9'` is not matching the 4 with a wildcard, it's matching the 9 in 19. See https://regex101.com/r/oA5fD1/1