# PowerShell if -like error

Tags: powershell

Not sure what's wrong with this script

```
$SSODelete= "Delete"
$SSOfiles = "SSo.xml" 
$channlename = "INC8-Patch"
write-host $channlename
if ($channelname -like *INC8*){ 
   $SSOarg = "$SSODelete $SSOfiles"
   Write-Host $SSOarg
}
```

It throws following error:

```
You must provide a value expression following the '*' operator.
At line:5 char:25
+ if ($channelname -like *INC8*){
+                         ~~~~~
Unexpected token 'INC8*' in expression or statement.
```

Tried using `"*INC8*"` and `'*INC8'` but it then it does not qualify `if` statement.

Adding screenshot for script and it's results
[Simple Script and results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6y9j.jpg)

Comment: `-like "*IMC8*"`

Comment: Quote the string

Comment: Tried that option but then if condition fails below is output
    PS D:\test> $SSODelete= "Delete"
 $SSOfiles = "SSo.xml" 
    $channlename = "INC8-Patch"
    write-host $channlename
    if ($channelname -like "*INC8*"){ 
       $SSOarg = "$SSODelete $SSOfiles"
       Write-Host $SSOarg
     }
 INC8-Patch

It does not write-host value of  $SSOarg

Comment: Probably because of a typo:
write-host $chann__le__name
if ($chann__el__name -like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerShell `-like` operator should be used with the matching string quoted, e.g., `$variable -like "*pattern*"`. `-like` accepts the simple wildcard (`*`) only; you can compare against regular expressions (regexps) by using `-match`. See [`Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators).

Comment: _accepts the simple wildcard (*) only;_ That's not true. `?` works as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778044/what-patterns-does-powershell-like-operator-support

Comment: I have wrote simple script  <br/>
   $channelname = "INC8-Patch-Config"  <br/>
   write-host "$channelname"  <br/>
   $channlename -like "*INC8"  <br/>

Still it's give value as false

PS C:\Users\sawantp> $channelname = "INC8-Patch-Config"  <br/>
write-host "$channelname"  <br/>
$channlename -like "*INC8"  <br/>

INC8-Patch-Config
False

Comment: The pattern `"*INC8"` will not match `"INC8-Patch-Config"`, because the pattern `"*INC8"` is looking for the string `"INC8"` at the end. If you want it to match anywhere in the string, you must use `"*INC8*"`.

Comment: > same result  > PS C:\Users\sawantp> $channelname = "INC8-Patch-Config"
> write-host "$channelname"
> $channlename -like "*INC8*"

> INC8-Patch-Config
> False

Comment: I can't reproduce these results. Check your code and values carefully.

Comment: Can someone please try in their ISE and check not sure how to paste image in reply

Comment: code: $channelname = "INC8-Patch-Config"
write-host "$channelname"
$channlename -like "*INC8*"   There is star in my code but somehow not getting displayed when i post

Comment: result PS C:\Users\sawantp> $channelname = "INC8-Patch-Config"
write-host "$channelname"
$channlename -like "*INC8*"

INC8-Patch-Config
False

Comment: You will need to supply a screen image somewhere, so that we can see exactly what you are typing and what the system is responding with. Your claimed results do not reproduce when I manually enter them on my system.

Comment: Added the screenshot in question

Comment: thanks for your help ... it was spelling mistake ... rectified

Comment: If you are using PowerShell 2 or later, you can put `Set-Strictmode -Version latest` at the top of your script and PowerShell will throw an error in cases like this, where you are referencing a variable that you never set a value for (because of the spelling error).

Comment: Thanks Jeff ... much appreciated for motivation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks , it was due to variable name i was comparing ... i need to be more cautious